# PHP use array_merge with N arrays

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I would like to group several (n) tables into a single large table. Exemple :

```
$tab1 = array("test0","test1");
$tab2 = array("test2","test3");
$tab3 = array("tes..","....");
```

But for example with 10 tables. Instead of writing

```
$result = array_merge($tab1, $tab2, $tab3 --> $tab10);
```

The algorithm should do this on its own, but I admit I'm lost. I thought I would do it recursively.

If anyone would have how to do it, thanks

Comment: So do you know how many and/or what these Arrays _(not tables)_ are called before trying to merge them all into one?

Comment: To me it looks like her   array( [0] => array([0]=>[0]="test"[1]= test2")  array[1] => array([0] =>"test3" [1] => "test4"  and this for 10 array. and I would like it to be  array[0]=test1 [2] = test2 [3] = test3 ......  In one big array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by not-using numerical variable names:
Instead I use an array:

```
<?php
$tab[] = array("test0","test1");
$tab[] = array("test2","test3");
$tab[] = array("test4","test3");
?>
```

Next: you can loop through them to merge

```
<?php 
$result = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($tab);$i++) {
   $result = array_merge($result, $tab[i]);
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: You don't need the loop, just use `...$tab`.

Comment: or use the foreach-loop. I use "For", as my first example needed it so.  The ...$tab is even nicer. But from which PHP version will it work?  Edit: PHP 5.6 (quite some time)

Answer (score 3):

Using `array_merge()` with all of the arrays in one main array can be simplified using the argument unpacking (or splat operator) `...`...

```
$tab[] = array("test0","test1");
$tab[] = array("test2","test3");
$tab[] = array("test4","test3");

print_r(array_merge(...$tab));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing comes to mind, it's not the prettiest, but it works. Without changing your array names.

It checks for `$$tab`, which is basically a variable starting with `'tab'` and ending with our incremented `$i`. Then it merges them one by one.

```
<?php

$tab1 = array("test0", "test1");
$tab2 = array("test2", "test3");
$tab3 = array("tes..", "....");

$i = 1;

$tab = 'tab' . $i;

$data = [];

while (isset($$tab)) {
    $data = array_merge($data, $$tab);
    $i++;
    $tab = 'tab' . $i;
}

print_r($data);
```

This is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => test0 [1] => test1 [2] => test2 [3] => test3 [4] => tes.. [5] => .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't introduce variables which you don't "use":

```
$tables = [];
$tables[] = ["test0", "test1"];
$tables[] = ["test2", "test3"];
$tables[] = ["tes..", "...."];
$mergedTables = [];
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $mergedTables = array_merge($tables, $table);
}
```